# Split two strings into one row in SQL (Access)

Tags: sql, string, ms-access, split

I have a table with strings:

```
Field1
150120154030
201012
```

And I want to insert the data from the two string rows into a table like this:

```
F1         F2  F3  F4    F5   F6
15012015   40  30 20   10   12
```

Any help to write the query for this?

Comment: Please add a complete sample data, With your current information; question is unclear ;).

Comment: Can you please add some more feilds and data of your example to propose a solution ...if your table have only these two row then you can do something like below..select substr(feild1,1,8) as f1,substr(feild1,9,2) as f2,substr(feild1,10,2) as f3,substr(field2 , 1,2) as f4,substr(field2,3,2)
from(
select feild1 , (
select field1  as f1
 from table
 qualify row_number() over (partition by feild1 order by field1)=2) as field2
 from table)z;

Comment: Then what you've tried so far ?

Answer (score 1):

How ever your question is unclear, I can think about a query like this:

```
SELECT 
    MAX(IIF(Field1 = '150120154030', P1, '')) As F1,
    MAX(IIF(Field1 = '150120154030', P2, '')) As F2,
    MAX(IIF(Field1 = '150120154030', P3, '')) As F3,
    MAX(IIF(Field1 = '201012', P1, '')) As F4,
    MAX(IIF(Field1 = '201012', P2, '')) As F5,
    MAX(IIF(Field1 = '201012', P3, '')) As F6
FROM (
    SELECT 
        Field1,
        MID(Field1, 1, LEN(Field1) - 4) As P1,
        MID(Field1, LEN(Field1) - 3, 2) As P2,
        MID(Field1, LEN(Field1) - 1, 2) As P3
    FROM yourTable) DT;
```